# can't sort array in descending order using external class

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

I need help with my java code regarding ascending order display, which I'm receiving error on the temp assignment ..specifically these two assignments listed

```
 Customer1Purchase[i].getProductId() = Customer1Product[j].getProductId();

 Customer1Purchase[i].getProductId() = temp;

error reads__[The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable]
```

below is my code when, part when user choose option 3:
********please let me know if I need to provide more information********
I'm new to stalk over flow..... Thanks

c1_pNumber relates to number of purchase by customer1
Condition when Customer Invoice Number is Entered
[c1_pNumber] is size or number of elements in array
Customer1Purchase[i].getProductId() Position of FirstElement

```
// user option 3 ..... using switch case       
                      
case 3:



               // allow user input 
                Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.print("Enter the Invoice Number: ");
                int invoice  = scan.nextInt();

                        
       // if condition is true it should loop to display arranged data in ascending order
       // condition where user input = invoice number in record

        if(invoice == c1_InvoiceNumber) {
 
                for(int i=0; i<c1_pNumber; i++) {
                    for(int j=i+1; j<c1_pNumber; j++) {
                                    
        if(Customer1Purchase[i].getProductId() > Customer1Purchase[j].getProductId()) {
                                        
                    int temp = Customer1Purchase[i].getProductId();
                    Customer1Purchase[i].getProductId() = Customer1Product[j].getProductId();
                    Customer1Purchase[i].getProductId() = temp;
                                        
                                 }
                             }  
                          }

                        System.out.print("Ascending Order: ");
                        for(int i=0; i<c1_pNumber-1; i++) {
                            System.out.println(Customer1Purchase[i]);
                        }
                        System.out.print(Customer1Purchase[c1_pNumber-1]);
                     }
```

Comment: `Customer1Purchase[i].getProductId()` calls a method which can't be assigned to anything. The return type might be an integer but you can't change the class member from there. You'll want a setter in your customer purchase class, so you can call `setProductId(...)`.

Comment: Also I would strongly advise to take note on your indentation and have a look at some Java naming conventions. It makes everything a lot clearer for you and us and helps to convey structure and intent.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion... I'll have a look